# probability that there is at least one defective part

Tags: statistics, probability

I study Economics and this is a statistic problem I am trying to solve - without great success, unfortunately. 
 
"A machine has a defect rate of 6%.
 a) Chosen at random 4 pieces (with replacement) from the production flow, compute the probability that none is defective. 
 b) In the event that extractions are performed 60, compute the probability that there is at least one defective part" 
 
 I have no idea how to answer the first question. What logical processes can I use? 
 Regarding the second question, I thought of using the binomial random variable with n = 60 and p = 0.06. 
 Then: P (X> = 1) = 1 - P (X <1) = 1 - P (X = 0) = 1 - [(binomial coefficient 60 and 0) * (0.06) ^ 0 * (0.94) ^ 60 = 1 - 0.02446 = 0.97558 
 
 Can somebody show me how to do it and explain the logical process behind it? Thank you.